# Inserting data into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was wondering if, like with OpenSearch, I can insert data to a database or datalake without the need of creating a table (From what I know I can't do that, but I'm not sure). Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share the use case?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake just recently released schema detection to public preview

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/schema-detection-public-preview/

You can also load files direct to s3 or an internal stage with various formats supported